# Get nested dict items using Jinja2 in Flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

for this dictionary with this Flask controller

```
projects = {
        'life-calc':{'url':'life-calc',
                    'title': 'Life Calculator'},
        'text-game':{'url':'text-game',
                    'title':'Text Adventure'},
        'fill-it-up':{'url':'fill-it-up',
                    'title':'Fill It Up'},
        'rock-paper-scissors':{'url':'rock-paper-scissors',
                    'title':'Rock, Paper, Scissors'},
        'bubble-popper':{'url':'bubble-popper',
                    'title':'Bubble Popper'}
            }


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
                            projects = projects)
```

and the template as such

```
    <h1>
        List of My Projects
    </h1>

    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href = "life-calc">Life Calculator</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "text-game">Adventure Game</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "fill-it-up">Fill It Up</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "rock-paper-scissors">Rock Paper Scissors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href = "bubble-popper">Bubble Popper</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <p>test section below</p>
    <ol>
        {% for project in projects %}
        <li><a href = "{{ project['url'] }}">{{ project['title'] }}</a> </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I access the items in the dict to print a list of my projects as in the HTML above the test?

I solved my own problem with help from [Rendering a python dict in Jinja2 / Werkzeug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141073/rendering-a-python-dict-in-jinja2-werkzeug)
The template block should be

```
{% for key, value in projects.iteritems() %}
<li><a href={{value['url']}}>{{value['title']}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I'm still curious as to how to access further nested dictionaries, and if this is the smartest way to create a simple menu.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you want to know how access the nested dict in template

If you think I got your question

Generally, This is the way to access the nested dictionary items in dictionary.

#### If the iterables are getting nested further just you have to increase the `forloop` depth level whether it is list or dict.

Here I am giving just a generic example in my own way for your understanding

#### Data:

```
parent_dict = {1: {'A':'val1','B':'val2'}, 2:{'C':'val3','D':'val4'}}
```

#### iteration in jinja2:

```
{% for key,parent_dict_item in parent_dict.items() %}
   {% for key2, nested_value in parent_dict_item.items() %}
      <li><a href = "{{ nested_value }}">{{ nested_value }}</a> </li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Answer:

```
<li><a href="val1">val1</a> </li>
<li><a href="val2">val2</a> </li>
<li><a href="val3">val3</a> </li>
<li><a href="val4">val4</a> </li>
```

Comment: I know this was posted almost two years ago, but is there a way to sort the nested dicts using this method? I had been using something like `{% for k, v in parent_dict|dictsort %}` but with this method I cannot use `dictsort`. Any ideas?

Comment: You can write the `template filters` to do it. It is available in django templates, jinja2 etc..[refer](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look! :)

Comment: iteration using .iteritems() is better than .items()

Answer (score 20):

Instead of expanding the key and value in the loop, you can also use the key to reference the item in the dict itself:

```
{% for project in projects %}
  <li><a href = "{{ projects[project].url }}">{{ projects[project].title }}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```