# How to access a dictionary value in a for [django, python, html]

Tags: python, django

I pass the `context` to html and I need to display the values in a for - by key.

is not displayed. how to refer to the value of a dictionary in a loop?

**print context**

`context = {'tag': 'fast', 'view': <orders.views.OrderAddView object at 0x0000000005AB30A0>, 1: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm'>, 2: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm2'>, 'count_form': range(1, 3)}`

**html**

```
 <form action="{% url 'order_add' tag %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for x in count_form %}
            {{ x.as_p }} - this does not work
        {% endfor %}
        {{ 1.as_p }} - it works
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add order</button>
    </form>
```

that is, how to access the values 1,2, etc. in a loop - `1: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm'>`?

perhaps it is necessary to specify `{{context [x] .as_p}}` in the loop? how to do it?

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141374/7618968) maybe helpful.

Comment: And why don't you simply pass the forms in a **list** instead of passing random variable names into the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all your forms in same list and then iterate **forms** key from your template :

```
context.update({'forms' : [Form1, Form2]})
```