# how to find a dictionary element using Jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have python dict object which I am passing to the template `{'bla bla': 'lalala'}`.
I want to reach this object with Jinja `{{ dict_name.'bla bla' }}` or `{{ dict_name.bla bla }}` or `{{ dict_name['bla bla'] }}` but all this not working. What i need do?

Comment: Is it solved by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)?

Comment: `{{ dict_name['bla bla'] }}` should work. You can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141073/rendering-a-python-dict-in-jinja2-werkzeug